# Why doesn't C# allow an else clause on loops?

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I decided to learn some Python (IronPython) syntax today.  In doing so, I was impressed by a construct that it allows with its loops.

Python supports an `else` clause on its loops.  An `else` on a loop basically says, "if this loop finished normally, then enter this clause".

Allow me to demonstrate using C#.

This code:

```
Something something = SomeCallToSetThisUp();
bool isCompatable = false;
foreach (Widget widget in widgets)
{
   isCompatable = widget.IsCompatableWithSomething(something);

   if (!isCompatable)
      break;
}
if (isCompatable)
   compatableSomethings.Add(something);
```

could become this code (not valid C#):

```
Something something = SomeCallToSetThisUp();
foreach (Widget widget in widgets)
{
   if (!widget.IsCompatableWithSomething(something));
      break;
}
else
   compatableSomethings.Add(something);
```

Having never seen this, it struck me as cool.  And once you learn it, it seemed as readable as any code I have seen.

While not universally needed (sometimes you want to affect every item in the list), I do think that it would be useful.

So, my question is: **Why isn't this in C#?**

I have a few ideas why:

- `break` can make debugging harder, so the designers did not want to encourage it.
- Not everything that is shiny can make it into the language.  (limited scope).

But those are just guesses.  **I am asking for an actual canonical reason**.

Comment: [Every feature starts at -100 points.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)

Comment: Probably also because it's not in C, C++, Java, or any other C-like language I'm aware of.  Also, to me `"if this loop finished normally, then enter this clause"` sounds like the opposite of what I'd expect it to do.

Comment: Asking why a language was not designed as you would design it is not a good question for SO.

Comment: I've always thought this was good, but I would prefer `andfinally` instead of `else`, which in C# would probably mean "if my `foreach` didn't have any iterations".

Comment: @AndyBrown yes, that reads much better to me.

Comment: I like the feature but using the keyword `else` here is a horrible design choice. Even though I *know* what it means I immediately read it as “execute this if the loop was never entered” *every. single. time.*

Comment: Your example could be written with an `if` and a Linq `All`.

Comment: @KirkWoll - not as I would do it, but why it differs from another existing (and quite popular) language.

Comment: @Vaccano, same difference, as regards its suitability for SO.

Comment: @KirkWoll - I disagree, but it would appear that 4 others agree with you, and that is all it takes to close...  Ah well...

Comment: @Vaccano, sometimes an unlucky gang will close a question that might not otherwise get closed.  If you believe in the legitimacy of this question, you should post a question on meta and you will at least get a better airing and perhaps some better explanations (or the community might agree with you on review and re-open this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual answer is because no-one asked for it or the cost of developing and maintaining it outweights the benefits.

From Eric Lippert's blog:

> I've already linked several times to Eric Gunnerson's great post on
>   the C# design process. The two most important points in Eric's post
>   are: (1) this is not a subtractive process; we don't start with C++ or
>   Java or Haskell and then decide whether to leave some feature of them
>   out. And (2) just being a good feature is not enough. Features have to
>   be so compelling that they are worth the enormous dollar costs of
>   designing, implementing, testing, documenting and shipping the
>   feature. They have to be worth the cost of complicating the language
>   and making it more difficult to design other features in the future.
>
> After we finished the last-minute minor redesigns of various parts of
>   C# 3.0, we made a list of every feature we could think of that could
>   possibly go into a future version of C#. We spent many, many hours
>   going through each feature on that list, trying to "bucket" it. Each
>   feature got put into a unique bucket. The buckets were labelled:
>
> Pri 1: Must have in the next version
>
> Pri 2: Should have in the next version
>
> Pri 3: Nice to have in the next version
>
> Pri 4: Likely requires deep study for many years before we can do it
>
> Pri 5: Bad idea
>
> Obviously we immediately stopped considering the fours and fives in
>   the context of the next version. We then added up the costs of the
>   features in the first three buckets, compared them against the design,
>   implementation, testing and documenting resources we had available.
>   The costs were massively higher than the resources available, so we
>   cut everything in bucket 2 and 3, and about half of what was in bucket
>   1. Turns out that some of those "must haves" were actually "should haves".
>
> Understanding this bucketing process will help when I talk about some
>   of the features suggested in that long forum topic. Many of the
>   features suggested were perfectly good, but fell into bucket 3. They
>   didn't make up the 100 point deficit, they just weren't compelling
>   enough.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/10/08/the-future-of-c-part-one.aspx

Additionally, you need to weight if the feature will be easily understood by existing / new developers. IMHO `else` on loop is not very readable, especially since the keyword for 'execute this block if the previous one finished OK' is `finally`.

What is more, I think `Enumerable.Any` / `Enumerable.All` methods are much better in this scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through a collection and checking a condition are different things, so they should be separate language constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Because for else loops are a hack from languages like python. If you feel like you need a for else loop, you should probably put that code in a separate function.

Comment: A bit more explanation would be nice: It’s actually quite a handy construct, use-cases crop up every now and again.